# Windows Azure and Metro-style apps in Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have atleast 5 billion ideas for a new App in Windows 8. However, most of them rely on a remote database connection.

Which is currently not possible in Metro apps. But I don't want just a work-around. Or an script that accesses an API which will access the DB and return results. So then I went to the MS forums and found a post somewhere (which I can't seem to find now) stating that I can just use Windows Azure SQL database and can connect to that one from within Windows Metro.

But I don't see any resources or documentation to back that up and I'm completely lost as to what to do.

Most apps these days, to offer any sort of personalized user experience need to communicate with the outside world and it's just impossible to do in Metro apps from what I can see.

Does anybody know if you can connect to a Windows Azure SQL DB from within a Metro style app? Any resources/Docs/Links/Samples you know of?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metro apps are optimized for tablets and generally CPU-and-battery constrained devices. Directly connecting to a database and processing the results is expensive in CPU, battery AND bandwidth terms.

What's more, database protocols aren't cachable and were not meant to deal with internet latencies. Your app could waste a lot of time trying and retrying to connect to the database each time the connection quality degraded.

The best option would be to a set of [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/odata.aspx) on top of your database and expose them to your application. It's easy to create a WCF Data Service on top of an Entity Framework model and the OData protocol used by WCF Data Services allows querying your entities using LINQ in an asynchronous manner. More complex processing can be done in the web server.

Comment: Metro apps are also for Desktops. That's why they're making touch-screen desktops now - IMO MS is making an incredibly big mistake here.

Comment: But it looks like I'll go with WCF. Wish me luck! :)

Comment: Agree. The piece no System.Data takes away is a local data store for disconnected operations.

Comment: You can use SQLite, check this post by Tim Heuer on how to do that http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/20/using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx The lack of local storage is a different can of worms

Comment: Yes SQLite is an option.  But I still want System.Data in WinRT.

Answer (score 1):

At this point Metro does not have a System.Data so there is no direct connect to the database.   You would need to communicate with the database via WCF to a Web Service.

Metro does have a user settings facility but I cannot find it right now. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR208189

The history is that the jumping off point for Metro was Silverlight.  Not saying that makes sense just what I have read.   It appears Microsoft wants to sandbox Metro for the Metro Store.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Not trying to be rude here; but what's User Settings got to do with connecting to a DB?

Comment: You asked about "personalized user experience"